# Error: Error creating IAM Role s3_access: MalformedPolicyDocument

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam

I am having this error when I run the terraform  `Error: Error creating IAM Role s3_access: MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource status code: 400,` What am I missing in IAM role? I am using this role to fetch a certain file from s3. I want to give limited permission to this role like only fetch certain bucket contents

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  count                       = var.ec2_count
  ami                         = var.ami_id
  instance_type               = var.instance_type
  subnet_id                   = var.subnet_id
  key_name                    = var.key_name
  source_dest_check           = false
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  #user_data                   = "${file("userdata.sh")}"1
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.ec2_sg.id]
  user_data       = "${file("${path.module}/template/userdata.sh")}"
  tags = {
    Name = "Webserver"
  }
}
resource "aws_iam_role" "s3_access" {
  name = "s3_access"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
              },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::webserver/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::webserver"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
EOF

  tags = {
    tag-key = "tag-value"
  }
}
resource "aws_security_group" "ec2_sg" {
  name        = "ec2-sg"
  description = "Allow TLS inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id

  ingress {
    description = "incoming for ec2-instance"
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "ec2-sg"
  }
}
```

Any type of help would be appreciated. I have tried doing it myself but I am stucked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "s3_access" {
  name = "s3_access"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
              },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"            
        }
    ]
}
EOF

  tags = {
    tag-key = "tag-value"
  }
}



resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "s3_access_policy" {

  name = "s3_access_policy"
  
  role = "${aws_iam_role.s3_access.id}"

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::webserver/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::webserver"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
EOF

}
```

Comment: It is giving me this error `Error launching source instance: InvalidParameterValue: Value (s3_access_policy) for parameter iamInstanceProfile.name is invalid. Invalid IAM Instance Profile name`

Comment: @aws-noob Hi. Your code in the question does not have an `iamInstanceProfile`. Is that a new issue?